# Get value from a text file and do calculation in UNIX environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

In unix shell, I have a txt file (Price.txt) that contain following information:

```
Buy value: 15
Sell value: 30
```

May I know how to use the command that can grep the buy value and sell value(in integer) and then do the difference between them, store in a new variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple `awk` script that will print the difference between sold value compared to the bought value *(doesn't matter which comes first in the file)*:

```
$ awk '/Buy value/{b=$3}/Sell value/{s=$3}END{print s-b}' file
15
```

Or if you know the `Buy value` always comes first you could be a little more concise:

```
$ awk '/Buy value/{b=$3}/Sell value/{print $3-b}' file
15
```

And if these are the only two lines in the file:

```
$ awk '{b?b=$3-b:b=$3}END{print b}' file
15
```

But the first script is the most robust and easily modified if you need to do more.

To store this result in a shell variable simple do:

```
$ diff=$(awk '/Buy value/{b=$3}/Sell value/{s=$3}END{print s-b}' file)

$ echo $diff
15
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
May I know what is the meaning of "$3"?
And one more question:
What if there is a timestamp before "buy value"?
i.e. 
130324_102345 Buy value:15
130325_102412 Sell value:30

Answer (score 1):

A very basic way would be:

```
buy=$(tail -1 YOUR_FILE | cut -d: -f2)
sell=$(head -1 YOUR_FILE | cut -d: -f2)
echo "the result is $(( $sell - $buy ))"
```

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without a comment!

Comment: I like the edit, @sudo_O, but I prefer it to be suggested in comments rather than having my answer edited.

Comment: I find comments messy.. I post `'you should drop the UUoC'` as comment, you fixed your answer and leave another comment, same outcome occurs but with unessercery comments that detract from the answer. A F.Y.I *your* answer isn't *your* answer it belongs to the community now. If I see an improvement can be made, I'll make it. Check out the FAQ for the official word http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: Uhms, I have a new view after reading the link you provide. Good to know this kind of edits can be done, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure shell solution that does not use any external programs:

```
#!/bin/bash

diff=0
while read bs value amount
do
    if [[ $bs == Buy ]]
    then
        diff=$(( diff - amount ))
    elif [[ $bs == Sell ]]
    then
        diff=$(( diff + amount ))
    else
        echo "$bs ignored!" >&2
    fi

done < Price.txt

echo "Difference: $diff"
```